# Hyperref option clash error because unknown package requires/loads it too

Tags: hyperref, errors, packages, logging, option-clash

I am currently hunting for errors in my template and these two I cannot solve after reading the log and researching:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 

The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
  []
```

I already ruled out

- Bibliography-styles requiring it
- Package not loaded last
- Putting global hyperref options in Documentclass options (even more errors)

My current knowledge is that some package/configuration file loads/requires hyperref. Therefore I looked at the log-file. But as a beginner I cannot decipher (a) which package causes the problem and (b) how I can solve/bypass it.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[
    ocgcolorlinks=false, %sample
]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{   
    urlcolor=red, %sample
}

\makeatletter
    \if@twoside
        \hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=TwoPageLeft, linkcolor=red}
        \fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using your code, I don't get any error if I load `bookmark` AFTER `hyperref`. Try it.

Comment: You need to load `bookmark` after `hyperref`: 1. The clash doesn’t exist anymore. 2. `bookmark` re-defines some `hyperref`’s macros.

Comment: I can imagine that this would be hard to debug given the number of places where I've read that `hyperref` should be the last package you load.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, but see also [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) And packages, which should be loaded after `hyperref`, often state this in their documentation. I know “often” is not “all”, though …

Answer (score 4):

Loading `bookmark` after `hyperref` solves the error.

See [Bookmark-Documentation](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bookmark.pdf) on page 7.